# How to run a gradle task before every build?

Tags: gradle

My build depends on resources generated from a build.xml. I've imported that build target to a Gradle task. When I run `$ ./gradlew buildlib`, the resources are successfully generated. For ci/cd, I need `$ ./gradlew buildlib` to run before every build. I've tried adding a `dependsOn` in gradle.build and adding `gradle buildlib` to the end of `gradlew` among other attempts in the code below. Nothing has worked.

How can I run this gradle task before every build?

```
ant.importBuild 'path/to/my/library/build.xml'
buildlib {
    doLast {
        println "Lib has been built, and resources have been generated"
    }
}

// Attempt 1.
build {
    dependsOn buildlib
}

// Attempt 2.
assembleRelease.dependsOn buildlib // Error: Could not get unknown property 'assembleRelease' for root project
assembleDebug.dependsOn buildlib // Error: Could not get unknown property 'assembleDebug' for root project

// Attempt 3. // Error: Could not get unknown property 'android'
project.afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def capitalizedVariant = variant.name.capitalize()
            def assembleVariantTask = project.tasks."assemble${capitalizedVariant}"
            assembleVariantTask.dependsOn buildlib
        }
    }
}    




// Attempt 4.
// gradlew
gradle buildlib
```

Comment: Attempt 1 is correct. Run `./gradlew build --dry-run` and you will see buildlib listed in the skipped tasks. Maybe buildlib doesn't do exactly what you think it does, or your ci/cd is running another task than build

Comment: After following your recommendation, you’re right: using attempt 1, I am seeing ‘buildlib’ run and the generated resources appear when I run ‘$ ./gradlew build’. I suspect that’s what happening when I, similarly, push the build or run buttons in Android Studio, but I’m not seeing ‘buildlib’ execute when in Android Studio, just on the command line. Is that expected?

Comment: It seems like Android Studio is running the build itself and not delegating to Gradle, and that is what you need. I'm not an Android Studio user but I do use IDEA which is similar (both JetBrains), and that is how IDEA works. This link to the IDEA docs has more on changing the setting https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#delegate_build_gradle